$h^0(X, 4H-5E)$ on weak Fano threefold
Let $X$ be a smooth weak fano threesfold arising as the blowup of a smooth curve $C$ of degree and genus $(d,g)=(10,2)$ in a rank 1 smooth fano threefold $Y$, $-K_Y^3 = 22$. Let $H$ be a hyperplane in $X$ and $E$ the exceptional divisor. What is $h^0(X, 4H-5E)$?
I think it can be 1 or 3, but not sure how to compute it directly.

It depends on which H you choose.

H here is the pullback of -K_X.
